# What does $a\in (D \cap(-\infty,a))'$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis

I have an exercise where I'm given:
$D \subset R$ 
$a\in (D \cap(-\infty,a))'$.
 This is on an introduction of limits and derivatives haven't been covered yet.

So what does the ' on the interval mean, and how can $a$ be in an open interval where $a$ is an endpoint that's cut off? I guess we can't say $5\in(0,5)$ right?

Comment: Presumably $'$ here represents the complement of the set.  $A' = \mathcal{X}\setminus A$ where $\mathcal{X}$ is the universe in question.  For example with the universe as $\Bbb R$ one has $(0,5)' = (-\infty,0]\cup [5,\infty)$.  Depending on the specific set $D$, you will have $(D\cap (-\infty,a))'$ will look a certain way, but in any of those since $a\not\in(-\infty,a)$ you will definitely have $a\in (D\cap (-\infty,a))'$

Comment: Ahh all right that seems quite logical, solving both questions at once. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the above notation occurs in connection with the limit

$(*)$ $\quad$ $ \lim_{x \to a-0}f(x)$

of a function $f:D \to \mathbb R$. The limit in $(*)$ can only be defined, if $a$ is an accumulation point of $D \cap(-\infty,a)$.

Sometimes the set of accumulation points of a set $A$ is denoted by $A'$.

Hence $a\in (D \cap(-\infty,a))'$ means: $a$ is an accumulation point of $D \cap(-\infty,a)$.